# Group by in one2many Fields in Odoo-8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Is it possible in a one2many fields to group by, I want to group a Employeelist in Project assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group by is possible only in tree views, not in One2many fields. Unfortunately.

Comment: I am having a requirement like that, are you sure it is not possible?

Comment: @naveen definitely

Comment: @Naveen unless of course you don't completely change yourself the whole JS part! but it would be a HUGE work